# Docker image unable to run postinstall script with error my_pck@2.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd my_pck@2.0.0 node symLink.js (wd=/build)

Tags: node.js, docker, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am building an docker image. My docker file is pretty simple as shown below:-

```
FROM node:10.15.3    

RUN mkdir /build
WORKDIR /build

COPY package.json .   
COPY . .

RUN ["npm", "install"]

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

The only thing i have extra is i have a postinstall script in package.json which does some extra stuff. The problem is when i try to run the install fails with below error:-

***postinstall script with error my_pck@2.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd my_pck@2.0.0 node symLink.js (wd=/build)***

I have looked into various posts and question reporting same issue where they suggest to use option of:-

1. using --unsafe-per in npm install does not help
2. I also tried adding in package.json but that also does not help.
3. I also tried adding in .npmrc file but unfortunately it also not helping.

I am running the following command to build docker image: ***docker build -t my_img:1.0 .***

I am using windows system.

Any Suggestion on how i can solve this.?

Comment: Can you share your post-install script?

Comment: @leopal Thanks for your response but unfortunately i wont be able share the script as it is internal. However, i can tell what i am doing in the script is generating symLink between the packages which are inside the node_modules folder.